# Wrong command in shell

Tags: shell

I have this command in a shell archive:

```
sh -c $POSTGRESbin'psql -U '$POSTGRESuser' -h localhost -d '$POSTGRESdb' -c "select preview from '$fildCatalog' where preview <>'nodata' and id_registro in (select distinct(id_record) from e3_article_items where id_catalog=2101 and id_article in (select id_article from document_articles where id_document in(select distinct(id_document) from p3_logical_pages where id_logical_page in (select id_logical_page from p3_flatplan_pages where id_edition=1536 and id_logical_page is not null order by cast(pagenumber as numeric)))));"' > $queryFolder$highFile"_"$previewFile;
```

But in <>'nodata' appear an error and I don't know how can I resolve it. The error is:

```
ERROR:  column "nodata" does not exist
LINE 1: select preview from XT_FIJOS where preview <>nodata and id_r...
```

Can anybody help me ?

Thanks !! 
                                                     ^

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using `'...'` to quote parts of the shell command, so you can't use them *inside* those parts of the command. Your SQL query therefore contains `nodata` instead of `'nodata'`, so it thinks `nodata` is supposed to be a column-name.

To fix this, you can use `"..."` instead of `'...'` where needed:

```
sh -c "${POSTGRESbin}psql -U $POSTGRESuser -h localhost -d $POSTGRESdb -c \"select preview from '$fildCatalog' where preview <> 'nodata' and id_registro in (select distinct(id_record) from e3_article_items where id_catalog=2101 and id_article in (select id_article from document_articles where id_document in(select distinct(id_document) from p3_logical_pages where id_logical_page in (select id_logical_page from p3_flatplan_pages where id_edition=1536 and id_logical_page is not null order by cast(pagenumber as numeric)))));\"" > "$queryFolder${highFile}_$previewFile";
```

(Note that `"..."` can contain a literal `"` by using `\"`, which makes it a bit more flexible.)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying with "...." and it's the same problem: 

LINE 1: ...lect preview from XT_HOUSE_PHOTOS where preview <>"nodata" a...
                                                        ^
Do you know any way to "escape" the quote '...' ???? 
Thanks

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't see it, but doesn't work :(. Now appear: LINE 1: ...lect preview from XT_HOUSE_PHOTOS where preview <>"nodata" a...

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way:

```
sh -c $POSTGRESbin'psql -U '$POSTGRESuser' -h localhost -d '$POSTGRESdb' -c "select preview from '$fildCatalog' where preview <>'\'nodata\'' and id_registro in (select distinct(id_record) from e3_article_items where id_catalog=2101 and id_article in (select id_article from document_articles where id_document in(select distinct(id_document) from p3_logical_pages where id_logical_page in (select id_logical_page from p3_flatplan_pages where id_edition=1536 and id_logical_page is not null order by cast(pagenumber as numeric)))));"' > $queryFolder$previewFile"_"$fildCatalog;
```

Thanks for your help !!